# post-fix lexical analyzer

Tags: python, compiler-construction

my assigment was to write an very simple lexical analyzer, for postfix expresions:

```
print ("enter each variable followed by a space" );
numbers = input("Enter the numbers: ") #ask for input

numbersArray = [] #array to store the input

for number in numbers:
    numbersArray.append(number)

numbersArray = numbersArray[::2]

print(numbersArray);

for x in numbersArray:

    if x == "_": print ( "     " , " delimeter" )
    elif x == "-": print ( "    ", " subtraction opp." )
    elif x == "/": print ( "    ", " divison opp." )
    elif x == "+": print ( "    ", " addition opp." )
    elif x == "*": print ( "    ", " multplication opp." )
    elif x == "0": print ( "    ", " Constant: 0 " )
    elif x == "1": print ( "    ", " Constant: 1" )
    elif x == "2": print ( "    ", " Constant: 2" )
    elif x == "3": print ( "    ", " Constant: 3" )
    elif x == "4": print ( "    ", " Constant: 4" )
    elif x == "5": print ( "    ", " Constant: 5" )
    elif x == "6": print ( "    ", " Constant: 6" )
    elif x == "7": print ( "    ", " Constant: 7" )
    elif x == "8": print ( "    ", " Constant: 8" )
    elif x == "9": print ( "    ", " Constant: 9" )
    elif x == "10": print ( "    ", " Constant: 10" )
    print(x)
```

a sample input: 3 _ 4 _ 5 _ +

the above is what ive started, this is my first time using python and ive been struggling with this. i was wondering if there was a better way i could recgonize bigger numbers and letters as constants and variable respectively ?

Comment: Usual way for the lexer part would be regular expressions (`re` module).

Comment: Take a look at `rply` or `ply` for python lex/parse libraries. If you are intent on writing your own, at least take a look at their source to get you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you both. I will look into both of them and let you know what happens

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that using a lexing library like [`ply`](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) is the easiest or best way to go. If you still want/are required to do it yourself, there are a couple things that need to change.

If you see something like `132`, you need to be able to skip to the of the number for the next loop iteration, so `for x in numbersArray:` doesn't work. You can just do a `while True`, track the loop index manually, and break out when you're done.

The most powerful to match your input to the lexeme is with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html). For example, you can match numbers with an optional decimal part using something like

```
import re
...
re.match(r'\d+(\.\d*)?', numbersArray[current_index:])
```

(Most number specifications are rather more "interesting" than this, so definitely don't copy over my regex. It will probably be wrong for what you need.)

You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to experiment and build your regex.

You could alternatively make use of Python's built in [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), such as `isnumeric` and `isalpha`. With this, your number check might look like

```
lexeme = ''
while numbersArray[current_index].isdigit():
    lexeme += numbersArray[current_index]
    current_index += 1
```

Comment: Nit-picks irrelevant to question/answer: strings are already iterable so copying everything over to `numbersArray` seems useless.  I believe your `x == "10"` check will fail.